# JavaScript array handling - ActiveX vs. FF add-on

Tags: javascript, activex, firefox-addon

**Question**

Is there a clean and robust way to handle calls to a plugin so that the caller can always expect to have a JavaScript array returned to them, regardless of whether the plugin is a Firefox add-on or an ActiveX control?  I've already got the actual plugin calls wrapped in functions, like:

```
function getDevice(deviceKey) {
    return plugin.getDevice(deviceKey);
}
```

I can change it to something like:

```
function getDevice(deviceKey) {
    return normalizeArray(plugin.getDevice(deviceKey));
}

function normalizeArray(array) {
    return typeof(array) == 'unknown' ? array.toArray() : array;
}
```

but I still need to remember to actually call normalizeArray from the wrapper functions, and the normalize implementation seems like it could be lacking in robustness and/or making some suspect assumptions.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

**Background**

I'm writing some JavaScript to interact with a plugin through JavaScript.  The plugin is available as an add-on in FF and as an ActiveX in IE.  There are a number of methods available in the plugin that return arrays.  In FF, calling:

```
typeof(retVal);
```

on the object returns 'object'.  I can do things like:

```
retVal.length;
retval[0];
```

and they work as expected.  When I make those same method calls in IE, calling:

```
typeof(retVal);
```

returns 'unknown' and calls like:

```
retVal.length;
retval[0];
```

are undefined.

I've done some debugging and discovered that what the ActiveX is really returning is an array of variants.  This object IS recognizable by JScript, and a JavaScript version of the array can be obtained by caling retVal.toArray().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the array normalisation part of the wrapper but keep it as a separate function so:

```
function getDevice(deviceKey) {
    return normalizeArray( plugin.getDevice(deviceKey) );
}
```

You're right, the `normalizeArray` function does seem a bit brittle. You might instead want to do an `instanceof` test, and even wrap it in try..catch as IE is known to do strange things when ActiveX objects are tested this way, so:

```
function normalizeArray(obj) {
  try {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
      return obj;
    }
  } catch(d) {}

  // Convert obj to array - see if toArray property is truthy
  if (obj.toArray) {

    // Is this syntax correct?
    // If it is, call it
    return obj.toArray();

  } else {

    // Not Array, no toArray(), what next?

  }
}
```

However I'm not sure if the object returned by your Firefox plugin is a javascript Array or if it's created in the same scope as the *normalizeArray* function (i.e. it might be created from a different Array constructor) so the *instanceof* test will fail even if it is an Array. An alternative test is:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]'
```

which I think should **definitely** be wrapped in try..catch for IE if there is any chance *obj* is an ActiveX object.

Incidentally, *typeof* is an operator, there is no need to use the grouping operator ().

Comment: I still wish there was a better way to actually force the normalization to happen, but your implementation is definitely nicer than what I had going on.